# How does a virus stick to a non-biological surface?

Tags: virology, coronavirus

Recent events has triggered an renewed interest in understanding how a virus is able to stay on a surface.

For sake of argument, let's assume we are dealing with a Corona-type virus. One can then speculate that a virus sticks to a (non organic) surface due to a London-force (a [Van der Waals force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force)) interaction between the surface and the virus *`Spike S protein`*. But I really have no idea and it's just a wild guess.

I'm looking for research and experiments on this topic but I can't find any, most likely because I am not asking Google the right question or using the correct biology language.

**How does a virus stay attached to a non-biological surface?**
(Are there any "stickiness" measures for this?)

PS. When I say *non-biological*, I mean *glass, metal* and *plastic*.

Comment: It might be useful to look into studies that have been done into colocalization of viruses and bacteria on (organic) biofilms (e.g., https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4993353/).

Comment: The virus never appears isolated. When it is distributed by droplets or feces that is the transportation medium. And those are sticky by them selfes.

Comment: @aggsol do aerosol droplets last days attached to surfaces even when said surface appears dry? Is it microscopic?